# How can I center the text for an ultragroupbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I have a Windows Form which contains an [UltraGroupBox](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.Misc.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraGroupBox.html).

How can I center the text on the UltraGroupBox?

Right now it looks like this:

[image: Picture of the form with the title left aligned]

Comment: The answers in your second link I think? ' Center the caption within the area of the header that it is being drawn. ' If you want to shift the location of the caption entirely, ' use the CaptionAlignment property. Me.UltraGroupBox1.HeaderAppearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Center

Comment: Yes that is correct. The caption alignment works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

' Center the caption within the area of the header that it is being drawn. ' If you want to shift the location of the caption entirely, ' use the CaptionAlignment property. Me.UltraGroupBox1.HeaderAppearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Center

**Edit**

It appears that you are able to use the `CaptionAlignment` property

[Documentation can be found here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.Misc.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraGroupBox~CaptionAlignment.html)

`this.ultraGroupBox1.CaptionAlignment = GroupBoxCaptionAlignment.Center;`

Comment: The `HeaderAppearance.TextHAlign` will only modify the text alignment within the context of the caption.